# setinterval function not working titanium mobile

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have the following code:

```
var c = null;
c = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();


var url = 'example.com';
c.open('GET', url);
Titanium.API.log('info', url);

c.onload = function() 
{
    Titanium.API.log('info', 'onload');

    setInterval(getPeople(), 5000);
};
c.send();
```

The code should access the getPeople() function every 5 seconds, but it does not. In fact, the application exists prematurely.

what Im I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either:

```
setInterval(getPeople, 5000);
```

or:

```
setInterval("getPeople()", 5000);
```